# Rails 3 and paperclip on update method issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Paperclip is working well to save a user avatar but I find an issue on update.

In my view, if the user has an image saved in the model it will show an image tag with the current image next to the file upload field so you can see what your current avatar is.

If the image has no changes but the model validation fails (like no first_name), the original display image disappears, meaning that the user either has to correct the error and re-select an image and submit (update) or go back and start over without the error. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Heres the code:

Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Validation
  validates :first_name, :presence => true

  # Paperclip
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "70x70#" }

end
```

Controller

```
...
  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.xml
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /users/1
  # PUT /users/1.xml
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
...
```

View

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <div class="row text">
    <%= f.label :first_name %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <%= f.label :avatar %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
    </div>
    <div class="field" id="avatar_upload">
      <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row actions"><%= f.submit %> or <%= link_to 'cancel', users_path %>.</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is being caused by your form sending 'nil' to the server (due to the field being blank since a new avatar is not being uploaded) when your page sends a POST request to your server. Short of mucking things up with hidden temporary fields, there are a few ways around this:

- Client-side validation. Prevent your page from submitting if anything is wrong and you won't end up reaching the server-side validation failure that results in the missing image.
- Move the avatar field to a separate FORM object on the same page that only handles the avatar. That will ensure that the page only ever sends avatar information in a POST message if it is related to an actual avatar edit.
- Move the avatar upload/update functionality to a completely separate page that only handles the avatar. This works for the same reason the reason above this one works.

Comment: Thanks! When you say form object do you mean literally a separate form or model or do you mean something like using fields_for within the same form? (Sorry, still quite new to rails!) Thanks for the reply.

Comment: The latter. By option two, I mean that you would write your view in such a way that it generates two form tags in your HTML source. Using fields_for, form_for, or any other method to start a new form in your view would work.